# Is there any way to recover deleted files which may have since been overwritten?

Tags: data-recovery

I deleted lots of files & folders on my laptop and then I put a new files in the same folders. I need to recover the deleted files. I tried a lot of recovery software and I couldn't recover my old files.

I read that if you refill the folders with new files after deleting old ones then I can't recover them again. Is that true?

What should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not technical support. You need to speak to someone familiar with your Operating System's file system.

Comment: What recovery software did you try? Depending on how much data has been written since they were deleted, you might be out of luck. It might not be what you want to hear right now, but this is the time to do it- do you have a working backup plan in place now for the future?

Comment: No, [there is no proven method](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html) to recover data that has been overwritten.

Comment: Just putting files in the same folder does not guarantee the old file were overwritten.

Comment: No; If you overwrote the data the the data overwritten cannot be restored.

Comment: You might try here: http://www.wikihow.com/Recover-Overwritten-Files

Comment: @BillOer that article is BS! If it has been overwritten it is gone forever.

Comment: @Moab, the article may be BS, but data once overwritten is not totally unrecoverable. The new data does not overwrite every single magnetic particle of the old file. I don't know how good the tools are that that article mentions, but the police and federal intelligence agencies frequently use data recovery tools to recovery overwritten data, just ask Hilary. Many companies make their employees use a tool that overwrites the old data over 16 times. These agencies often use tools to recover data that users thought were not recoverable.

Comment: Did you check if they're still in the Recycle Bin?

Comment: BillOer: There is no source I can find that suggests that that is possible, and several that have done detailed analysis and concluded otherwise.

Comment: When you say you tried a lot of recovery software, was it low-level recovery that you tried (reconstructing files from scraped raw data rather than "undeletion")?  If the files have actually been overwritten, you ask whether there's any way to recover them.  There's a theoretical answer and a practical answer.  You're probably interested in the practical answer.  While people can debate the theory of whether it can be done and whether spy agency can do it, there is no argument that there is nothing available to consumers that will recover overwritten files.

Comment: @BillOer your nitpicking, if a file has been overwritten purposely, there is no recovery method that will recover the file, no one has ever done it. If I zero fill a hard drive nobody can recover anything, its never been done.

Answer (score 6):

If the data has actually been overwritten it cannot be recovered.

Here is the 1996 paper that originated the claims that it's possible: Peter Gutmann: "[Secure Deletion of Data from Magnetic and Solid-State Memory](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html)" ([also here](http://www.usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/sec96/full_papers/gutmann/index.html)).

To be fair, Dr. Gutmann notes in his first epilogue to the paper:

> Another point that a number of readers seem to have missed is that this paper doesn't present a data-recovery solution but a data-deletion solution. In other words it points out in its problem statement that there is a potential risk, and then the body of the paper explores the means of mitigating that risk.

In other words, the paper was not claiming to prove that recovery of overwritten data was possible. He was only showing reasons to believe that it was *plausible,*  and proposing overwrite patterns that should be sufficient to preclude such recovery. (Although, since he apparently never actually demonstrated any recovery of overwritten data, he could not have tested those patterns, so their efficacy remains as unproven as their necessity.)

However, the papers linked below show that the risk is far, far smaller than claimed.

(I feel compelled to mention that Dr. Gutmann is also famous for claiming that Windows Vista's anti-piracy, DRM enforcement features would use so much energy as to contribute noticably to global warming. George Ou: "[Claim that Vista DRM causes full CPU load and global warming debunked!](http://www.zdnet.com/article/claim-that-vista-drm-causes-full-cpu-load-and-global-warming-debunked/)" (2007).)

In the following sections I will cite several papers that disagree with Dr. Gutmann's claims about the *possibility* of recovery of overwritten data.

---

Daniel Feenberg, National Bureau of Economic Research: "[Can Intelligence Agencies Read Overwritten Data?](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html)"  (2003, rev. 2013) thoroughly analyzed Gutmann's claims and found them "much overwrought". The presentation is fairly nontechnical and provides a good "starting point" for the subsequent papers. (Note, this link was previously posted in the question comments by Moab. 
Note also: In the below quotation, and in the rest of this answer, "MFM" refers to "Magnetic Force Microscope", a microscope that reveals magnetization patterns at very high resolution, rather than "Modified Frequency Modulation", the now-obsolete technique for recording data on hard drives. "MFM" is *also* used in the latter context in Gutmann's paper and in some of the papers linked below.)

> Gutmann mentions that after a simple setup of the MFM device, that
>   bits start flowing within minutes. This may be true, but the bits he
>   refers to are not from disk files, but pixels in the pictures of the
>   disk surface. Charles Sobey [...] suggests that it would take more
>   than a year to scan a single platter with recent MFM technology, and
>   tens of terabytes of image data would have to be processed.

and:

> A single write is sufficient if the overwrite is truly random, even
>   given an STM microscope with far greater powers than those in the
>   references. In fact, data written to the disk prior to the data whose
>   recovery is sought will interfere with recovery just as must as data
>   written after - the STM microscope can't tell the order in which
>   magnetic moments are created. It isn't like ink, where later
>   applications are physically on top of earlier markings.

and:

> Recently I was sent a fascinating piece by Wright, Kleiman and Sundhar
>   (2008) who show actual data on the accuracy of recovered image data.
>   While the images include some information about underlying bits, the
>   error rate is so high that it is difficult to imagine any use for the
>   result. While the occasional word might be recovered out of thousands,
>   the vast majority of apparently recovered words would be spurious.

(The paper by Wright *et al* is the paper I cover in the next+1 section.)

> Another fact to ponder is the failure of anyone to read the "18 minute
>   gap" Rosemary Woods created on the tape of Nixon discussing the
>   Watergate break-in. In spite of the fact that the data density on an
>   analog recorder of in the 1960s was approximately one million times
>   less than current drive technology, and that audio recovery would not
>   require a high degree of accuracy, not one phoneme has been recovered.

---

Feenberg links to a paper by Charles Sobey: "[Recovering unrecoverable data](http://www.forensicfocus.com/recovering-unrecoverable-data)". (The link he uses is stale; this one is live at the moment.) However Sobey's paper is about recovery of data from failed drives, not overwritten ones:

> If the disk is not physically damaged, the user's data is still there,
>   **unless** it has been overwritten. (emph. added - jeh)

---

Craig Wright, Dave Kleiman, and Shyaam Sundhar R.S.: "[Overwriting Hard Drive Data: The Great Wiping Controversy](http://www.vidarholen.net/~vidar/overwriting_hard_drive_data.pdf)" (2008) is a more technical paper. The authors *tested* Gutmann's theory of use of a magnetic force microscope (Gutmann apparently never did, never claimed to have) and found it wouldn't work.

The gist of their argument is this: Old data does have an effect on the magnetic fields that result when new data overwrites it; however, they show (with actual data) that the effect is extremely weak. It is of the same order as the signal variations - noise - encountered "naturally" when reading even a formerly-pristine drive, *and the two cannot be reliably separated*. i.e. variations in magnetic field strength that are due to the noise that is normal in the operation of a hard drive, and those that are due to old data, cannot be distinguished from each other.

> The fact is, with modern drives (even going as far back as 1990) that
>   this entire process is mostly a guessing game that fails significantly
>   when tested.

In addition, they state that the underlying theory behind recovery of overwritten data is unsupportable:

> The argument arises from the statement that “each track contains an
>   image of everything ever written to it, but that the contribution from
>   each ``layer" gets progressively smaller the further back it was
>   made”. **This is a misunderstanding** of the physics of drive functions
>   and magneto-resonance. There is in fact no time component and the
>   image is not layered. It is rather a density plot. [emph. added - jeh]

and

> the level of recovery when presented with a perfect image is too low
>   to be of use even on a low density pristine drive (which does not exist
>   in any actual environment).

and

> Consequently, we can categorically state that there is a minimal (less
>   than a 0.01% chance) of recovering any data on a NEW and unused drive
>   that has a single raw wipe pass (not even a low-level format). In the
>   cases where a drive has been used (even being formatted for use) it is
>   not possible to recover the information – there is a small chance of
>   bit recovery, but the odds of obtaining a whole word are small.

---

Gordon Hughes and Tom Coughlin: "[Secure Erase of Disk Drive Data](http://www.tomcoughlin.com/Techpapers/Secure%20Erase%20Article%20for%20IDEMA,%20042502.pdf)" (2004) reaches similar conclusions for "exotic" analog analysis of the signal recovered from the heads.

They show that it is possible to show weak correlations between recovered signals and old data, but *only if you already know what the old data was.* This is obviously forensically useless. If you have nothing to try to correlate with, then the residual effects of old data on the signal are indistinguishable from noise. This is the same conclusion made in the paper cited previously by Wright, Kleiman, and Sundhar, but reached by analysis of electrical signals instead of MFM images.

They conclude:

> One erasure pass appears to be sufficient to make old data unrecoverable.

Also, regarding MFM "pictures" of the magnetic domains:

> It is easy to obtain pictures that appear to show unerased track edge
>   data. But no one has shown complete recovery of a data sector,
>   including the data synchronization preamble, bit de-randomizer,
>   partial response and modulation codes, and error correction code.

---

I will add a final thought of my own: If it were possible to write two different sets of data to the same physical area of the drive and recover both reliably, the hard drive makers would have been all over this years ago. They would have been using the drive's apparent ability to store two different items of data in the same place to increase the drive's usable capacity. This clearly has not happened.

Answer (score -2):

Did they go into the trash can? Modern operating systems use the trash can paradigm. Files are not deleted on the spot, but just *moved* to a special repository.

If the space occupied by the file(s) has been liberated, the OS *may* reuse that space on the very first occasion. This means, that this space cannot be reclaimed to reconstruct the deleted file.

It's like the blackboard in the classroom. If the content has been wiped out, you may, if looking carefully at the board reconstruct the content. If it has been wiped really clean or if it has been overwritten, the former data is lost. If it has been partially overwritten, you may be able to reconstruct partially your lost data.

Answer (score -4):

I don’t know which Operating System you’re mentioning, but, yes, you CAN recover the files if they’re in HDD.

Magnetic disks can spread information for its surface (the topmost layer from disk) to the deeper layers due to magnetic properties. A good program can read information in all these layers (hundreds and thousands of times each sector), comparing all these sector readings and trying to recover the original information, that will be statisticaly the most common for each sector.

If the files were normally deleted (not a DoD 5220-22M method), you may try SpinRite to recover them.

But its operation, just due its characteristics, is really slow and may consume a lot of hours, depending of the HDD speed (disk and controller).

Comment: This is incorrect. There are no "layers" containing traces from different times in history and there is no software that can recover data that has been actually overwritten. Hardware-based recovery methods have  been talked about but turn out not to be feasible either.

Comment: If it has been overwritten it is gone forever.

Comment: SpinRite does not revive overwritten files, it just fixes damaged sectors.

Comment: In practice any spreading on the surface is miniscule, and it is not possible for software to detect it.  It may be theoretically for extremely well funded agences to recover some data using tunneling microsocopes, but even if this can be doable, the huge costand error rate will probably make it a non-starter for anyone who is not an NGO trying to get extremely valuable secrets.  You should restore your data from backups.  If you don't have backups you should kick yourself.  If you were not told the importance of backups you should go after whoever taught you.

Comment: thx all for ur answers ,, now i lost my data forever :( ,, i will kick myself

Comment: i do not think so spinrite really can do that. it is hard to recover the overwritten data, may need professional group to do it.